# Generating data dictionary for SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-dictionary

I am trying to generate a data dictionary for a table in my database.

Ideally I would like to export the column names, data type, restrictions and extended property descriptions.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get at this via a combination of `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and using [`fn_listextendedproperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179853.aspx).

Comment: This didn't work for me, can you give me some feedback. here is error I get `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`

Comment: Your error indicates you tried this on Oracle.  This is a SQL Server answer to a SQL Server question.

Comment: Thanks mattmc3. Do you know how to do this on Oracle?

Answer (score 13):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT
    IC.COLUMN_NAME,
    IC.Data_TYPE,
    EP.[Value] as [MS_Description],
    IKU.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
    ITC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
    IC.IS_NULLABLE
 FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC
    INNER JOIN sys.columns sc ON OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(IC.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(IC.TABLE_NAME)) = sc.[object_id] AND IC.COLUMN_NAME = sc.name
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties EP ON sc.[object_id] = EP.major_id AND sc.[column_id] = EP.minor_id AND EP.name = 'MS_Description' AND EP.class = 1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE IKU ON IKU.COLUMN_NAME = IC.COLUMN_NAME and IKU.TABLE_NAME = IC.TABLE_NAME and IKU.TABLE_CATALOG = IC.TABLE_CATALOG
    LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS ITC ON ITC.TABLE_NAME = IKU.TABLE_NAME and ITC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = IKU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE IC.TABLE_CATALOG = 'Database'
  and IC.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
  and IC.TABLE_NAME = 'Table'
order by IC.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

or schema documentation generator like [Dataedo](http://dataedo.com) *(which I am the Product Manager of)*.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a data dictionary of your SQL Server database, I suggest you use [ERBuilder data modeller](https://soft-builder.com/), just follow these steps:

To generate an ER diagram it is necessary to first, reverse engineer your database select: Menu -> File -> Reverse Engineer the ER diagram will be displayed in ERBuilder.
To generate a data dictionary of your database select: Menu -> Tool -> Generate model documentation

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first search result for 'mssql data dictionary', here's a simple query to get the list of tables and columns in a db -

```
select table_name, ordinal_position, column_name, data_type 
from information_schema.columns 
order by table_name, ordinal_position;
```

giving eg

```
"table_name","ordinal_position","column_name","data_type"
Account,1,Account,varchar
Account,2,Type,varchar
Account,3,Description,varchar
Account,4,Rollup_Account,varchar
Account,5,Last_Updated,datetime
Account,6,Section_Name,varchar
Account,7,QB_ID,varchar
Additional_Charge,1,Additional_ChargeKey,int
Additional_Charge,2,Additional_Charge,int
...
```